# Angular 6 update issue "ng update"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[image: I am trying to update angular version 5 to 6. Using "ng update" command. i have facing issue. I have attach screen shot. How resolve this issue]
I am trying to  update angular version 5 to 6. Using "ng update" command. i have facing issue. I have attach screen shot. How resolve this issue

Comment: I think you need to be on node 8.9+ to work with the new CLI. Try updating node and see of that helps.

Comment: Check your node_modules folder. I had this issue as well and my node_modules folder was empty. I had to run `npm install` before `node_modules/.bin/ng update` for this to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update Node js (8.8) and NPM

Answer (score 0):

please use the official upgrade guide which help you what you need to do for upgrade your angular project:

https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Problem is resolve by updating Node js version  Above 8+. Thanks Richards

Comment: Does package-lock.json keep versions from being updated? For example, I have "@angular/cli" version 1.6.3 in my package-lock.json, and I think this is keeping my cli from updating to the new version. "@angular/common" and other core modules are in there also at 5.1.2, and I think this is keeping the update to 6 from happening. Not sure if I should remove these from the package-lock.json???